# Change headers on Github pages

Tags: github, https, http-headers, clickjacking

I am trying to make my website not prone to clickjacking. To do this I need to update the HTTPS headers. My website is hosted on github pages. How can I update the headers in github pages?

Answer (score 0):

So you can enforce https on github pages by checking this checkbox here: [image]

It takes some time to reflect.
Also, if it is not working, some of your css/JS files must be accessed over HTTP, so if any of the external dependencies of your website are requested over HTTP, change that to HTTPS and then it should work fine.